# Making a legend when some of the data sets could be empty

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, legend

For my project I have six sets of data to put on a scatter plot, like so:

```
plot(ax, ay, '.r', bx, by, '.b', cx, cy, '.m', dx, dy, '.c', ex, ey, '.y', fx, fy, '.k');
```

Sometimes these sets of data will be empty, so `bx` and `by` might have nothing in them, therefore getting skipped over.

Is there any way to build a legend that will match the right label to the right color piece of data? In other words, data in the `[cx, cy]` would always match the label `'c'` on the legend next to a magenta dot, even when there is no `'b'`. My current legend is as follows:

```
legend('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', -1);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Not easily, the values of the variables are arrays from values read in from excel. for example, ax is a list of x coordinates like [1,2,3,4] and ay is the corresponding y coordinates. The problem is, when the arrays bx and by are empty (because the spreadsheet didn't have data there) the labels in the legend don't work. I can edit the op to show what I have the legend doing right now, but it is hard for me to give variable values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the results you want if you first replace any sets containing [empty data](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isempty.html) with [`NaN`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nan.html) values. For example:

```
x = [];
y = [];

if isempty(x) || isempty(y)
  x = nan;
  y = nan;
end

plot(1:10, rand(1,10), 'r', x, y, 'g', 1:10, rand(1,10), 'b');
legend('r', 'g', 'b');
```

[image]

Leaving `x` and `y` as empty would give a warning when creating the legend and result in an incorrect legend. When passing empty vectors (`[]`) to the [`plot`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html) command, it simply doesn't create a [line object](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/line.html) for that data. When passing a `NaN` value, it creates *but doesn't render* a line object, so it still exists and can have a legend entry generated for it.

Answer (score 1):

One other possibility that does not use the `x=NaN;` is to use a 'dummy plot' out of the boundaries.

The drawback of this process is that you need to select the boundaries manually and if you made any changes in the main plots, you need to manually change the dummy plot as well. Bad idea for use in automated plots. Also If the legend is deleted and called again (either in the *insert* menu or by `legend off; legend show`)

The advantage is that you can plot it in a different order from the legend. This can be important when plotting multiple line types and thickness that overlay in some regions. In the figure below, for instance, if you plot the green first, it will disappear in the region *x<5* under the blue line.

An example of code:

```
x_e = [];
y_e = [];

figure() 

hold on
plot(100,100, '--g', 100,100, 'r', 100,100, 'b');   %dummy plot

x=1:10;
y=[1 3 3 3 3 4 5 6 9 10]/10;
y2=[1 3 3 3 3 7 6 6 4 3]/10;

plot(x,y2, 'b',x_e, y_e, 'r',x, y, '--g','linewidth',2);
set(gca,'box','on',... %box just to be prettier 
    'Xlim',[1 10], 'Ylim',[0 1]) % relevant set up!
legend('data 1', 'data 2', 'data 3');
```

and it give this graph:
[image]

Comment: I don't get the advantage here over the other answer, can you demonstrate it in your example?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I plotted the first exemple i reminded. I often use this technique as it allows to have a single legend over multiple plots, but i was not sure to add, so left out of here as is a bit out of the scope.

Comment: When I run your example I get [different result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dbmbh.png)

Comment: I'm using 2014b. Even if i move the legend call to last line it got the same output (as there is just 3 name entries). To reproduce it, i need to delete the legend and ask it again from the matlab _insert_ menu options.

Comment: I'm able to reproduce your plot in 2017a if I move the `legend` call to the last line (but then again if I type `legend off, legend show` after it I get the output as in my comment). I suggest that you move the legend creation to the last line so future readers (whom will probably have newer versions) will be able to reproduce it easily.

Comment: Thanks for noting that. I already update the answer and the code piece accordingly. BTW, quite interesting to change order of plotting as well.

Answer (score 1):

To complete [@gnovice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45445022/2627163) with the advantage proposed in [@Guto answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45462505/2627163), if the order of the lines matters, you can still use NaN, and set their order after it:

```
x = 1:10;
% plot and get the handle to the lines:
p = plot(x,x,'--g',nan,nan,'r',x,x,'b','linewidth',2);
% set the order of the lines from front to back:
set(p(1).Parent,'Children',p(1).Parent.Children([3 2 1]))
% add the legend:
legend('data 1', 'data 2', 'data 3');
```

In the above example we bring the green line on top of the blue one:

[image]